# Intellij Gradle error build target

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I made new android proiect in intelij 14.0.3 and I get this error

```
Error:Android Gradle Build Target: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/home/zaker/Development/gradle-2.2.1'.
```

I can't find any solution?

In build.gradle I set classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'`

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028909/intellij-idea-log-gradleconnectionexception-could-not-execute-build-using-gradl) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673636/gradle-error-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution) same question

Comment: it would help us to help you if you included code